# How can set timeout using Dio?

Tags: flutter, dio

I am using Dio Package and I want to know how can I set timeout because it is taking so long time ?, and I want to understand about Option Class that has (sending timeout, receive Timeout , etc ) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle timeout error with Dio in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769939/how-to-handle-timeout-error-with-dio-in-flutter)

Comment: no because I don't want handle I asked if I can set timeout mean reduce the waiting of timeout to appear the error and my question also about understanding the Option class @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Options specification.
https://pub.dev/packages/dio#request-options

And you can just add timeout like below without Options parameter.

```
final response = await dioClient
          .post(
            url,
            options: Options(headers: config),
            data: data,
          )
          .timeout(Duration(seconds: 3));
```

Comment: TimeoutException (TimeoutException after 0:00:20.000000: Future not completed) this error this mean that the future function does not complete so this error not type from DioError types @kuku

Answer (score 0):

You can use BaseOptions for different timeouts

```
final BaseOptions _options = BaseOptions(
  baseUrl: baseUrl,
  validateStatus: (status) => true,
  connectTimeout: 30000,
  sendTimeout: 30000,
  receiveTimeout: 90000,
  // responseType: ResponseType.plain,
);

final dio = Dio(_options);
```